# $\alpha$ root of $x^{p^{d}} - x$ then it is a root of $x^{p^{ds}} - x$

Tags: polynomials, roots

I want to prove that if $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{p^{d}} - x$ and $n=d\cdot s$, then $\alpha$ is also a root of $x^{p^{n}} - x$.
So far I know that $x^{p^{d}-1} =1$ and I've tried this:
$$x^{p^{n} -1} = x^{p^{ds}-1}$$
I have also tried:
$$x^{p^{n}} = x^{p^{ds}} = (x^{p^{d}})^s=\alpha^s$$
but I can't conclude that $\alpha^s=\alpha$. Can someone help me?

Comment: $x^{p^{ds}} \not= (x^{p^{d}})^s$

Comment: Sometimes $\frac{x(x^k-1)}{x(x^m-1)}$ is a polynomial

Comment: $p^d-1$ is a factor of $p^{ds}-1$ (and the claim follows). See, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7473/11619) where we have a more general result. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1561927/11619) is possibly more directly applicable.

Comment: Your specific question is also frequent within the tag [tag:finite-fields].